# What is equivalent of contentInset property on NSTextView?

Tags: macos, nstextview

I am developing macOS application and want to add NSTextView. I could not find contentInset property on NSTextView. How to set contentInset for NSTextView? Following is iOS code, what is macOS equivalent for the same?

```
UITextView* textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: You said `NSTextView` twice in your question, `NSTextField` once and in a tag.  Which is it?

Answer (score 6):

This one worked for me:

```
  self.textView.textContainerInset = NSSize(width: 30, height: 30)
```

Comment: For objective-c: `self.textView.textContainerInset = NSMakeSize(30, 30);`